# Identifying a particular row in a database

Tags: sql, android-studio, methods

This might seem like a pretty trivial question, but I couldn't come up with an answer.

I have an orders table for this app (school project) that I'm making. It has all the common fields like an order id, customer id, product id, and others. What I intend on doing is creating a recyclerview to display the orders as a sort of scroll able list for each customer. However, how will i be able to differentiate between 2 orders that a customer makes? What separates them is their order id. However, I set this to be an auto-incrementing integer primary key. So when I add the row, the order id is generated.
Is there any solution to retrieving this primary key, or do I need to find another solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can select the order_id (and other columns) as well as filter by the customer_id. Something like this:

```
SELECT order_id, product_id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = 123;
```

Comment: I understand this line, however i do not think it will work. Let's say a customer with id 123 makes an order. When this is added to the table a new record is created with, let's say, order id of 20. Now he makes another order. So now there are two records with customer id as 123. How will the computer differentiate between the two? This might work for the first time a customer makes an order.

Comment: @A.K SQL statements generally operation in sets. The above line selects all the rows that match the condition. If the customer has 0 orders, you'll get 0 rows returned. If the customer has 8 orders, you'll get 8 rows returned.